# Rails: Validate uniqueness ignoring some records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We're using Ruby on Rails 4.

My "event" model has:

- A "title" field which can be an arbitrary string
- A convention_id field which is a index into the Convention table
- A status field which can be "Proposed", "Discussing", "Accepted", "Rejected" or "Dropped".

I want to create a validates statement that ensures that the title is unique within a convention.  That's the easy part.

```
validates :title, :uniqueness => { :scope => :convention_id }
```

does most of what I want.  But I want to ignore any records which have a status of "Rejected" or "Dropped".  What I really want is to add some WHERE clauses to the SQL RAILs is generating, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any luck with this so far?

Comment: I think you need to write custom validation to achieve that, unless you'd introduce another column, let's call it `active`. If first three statuses where `active` and latter two not, then you could use a scope `:scope => [:convention_id, :active]`

Comment: Of course then `active` is replicating information from the `status` column, which is generally a bad idea.

I'll start exploring how to write a custom validation.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say you want to ignore rejected or dropped records?

Comment: Records with status set to "Rejected" or "Dropped" can have a duplicate title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer.  The following appears to work as I expect:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :title,  
  scope: :convention,  
  conditions: -> { where.not(status: ['Dropped', 'Rejected']) }
```

The SQL generated is

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM "events"
  WHERE ("events"."title" = 'Panel' AND 
         "events"."id" != 2 AND 
         "events"."convention_id" = 1) AND
        ("events"."status" NOT IN ('Dropped', 'Rejected'))
  LIMIT 1
```

Which I think is exactly what I want.

Thanks again for you help.

Comment: The answer I provided produces an even more concise SQL query. Can you illuminate how this answer satisfies your question more effectively?

Comment: The solution using the unless clause was checking the event being validated instead of comparing against the events already in the database.  So when I created an event and set it's status to dropped, and then created a second event, the second save failed since it was finding a match.  With the conditions clause, the second save succeeds since the first event has a status of 'Dropped' and doesn't match the query.

Answer (score 2):

[Per the canonical guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless), you can pass a [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html) with conditions for exclusion:

```
validates :title, 
  uniqueness: {scope: :convention_id},
  unless: Proc.new { |event| event.status == "Rejected" || event.status == "Dropped" }
```

Note that the use of the hash rocket (`=>`) must be consistent. In the example above, I've replaced the hash rocket syntax with JSON-style notation (de-facto for Rails 4), but the entire statement can be rewritten to utilize hash rockets as follows:

```
validates :title, 
  :uniqueness => {:scope => :convention_id},
  :unless => Proc.new { |event| event.status == "Rejected" || event.status == "Dropped" }
```

Comment: That doesn't do it.  It fails with the error {:title=>["has already been taken"]}

And development.log doesn't show the WHERE clause on the SQL.

Comment: I think this does opposite of what OP wanted. OP asks if there is a way for object to be valid if title is unique within the convention, except `Rejected` or `Dropped` ones. What you wrote would allow to add Rejected/Dropped record instead.

Comment: The way I interpret the question, the OP wants to validate records that __are not__ rejected or dropped, which is what this should do. The question is not well worded, quite frankly.

Comment: @user2062850, why do you necessitate the `WHERE` clause? I've inspected this query and it should indeed accomplish the desired outcome you've specified in your question and follow-up comments.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is needed to skip checking against events which have a status of 'Rejected' or 'Dropped'.  I created an event, set it's status to 'Dropped' and saved it.  Then I created a second event with the same title and attempted to save it.  The code above rejected the second save because it was matching the title of the first event, despite the status being set to 'Dropped'.  The solution below using the `conditions` clause adds a `WHERE` clause to the SQL to skip looking at any rows with a status of 'Dropped' or 'Rejected', so the second save succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to create the validation using `validates` as per [rubocop](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.35.1/RuboCop/Cop/Rails/Validation) could be

```
validates :title,
          uniqueness: { scope: :convention, conditions: -> { where.not(status: ['Dropped', 'Rejected']) }
```